# gen_random_uuid() as token for application

Tags: postgresql, security, uuid

I'd like to use the PostgreSQL function `gen_random_uuid()` from [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgcrypto.html#AEN160804) to generate application tokens (API keys). Will these be sufficiently random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gen_random_uuid()` function produces a standard [version 4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29). That gives you 122 bits of randomness which is about as good as it gets: "only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%".